# display image in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel, image, display

What i am trying to do is that i have to show Username and his image on dashboard panel. So images name are stored in database. i am doing when user login if his detail of login is correct then save his username and image name in session now i want to get image name using session on View side. here is my code. it showing me error how to solve this issue ?

UserController

```
public function login(Request $request){
    $user = User::where('user_name',$request->username)- 
      >where('password',$request->password)->get();

    if(count($user) == 0){
        return "No";
    }

    Session::put('username',$request->username);
    Session::put('name',$user[0]->name);
    Session::put('image',"/dist/img/".$user[0]->picture);

    return "Yes";
}
```

View

```
     <div class="sidebar">
                <!-- Sidebar user (optional) -->
                <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
                    <div class="image">
                        <img src= "{{URL(Session::get('picture'))}}" 
                      class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image">
                    </div>
                    <div class="info">
                        @if(Session::has('name'))
                        <a href="#" class="d-block">{{ 
                           Session::get('name')}}</a>
                        @endif
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: You did not display the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You using the `image` key to put session data:

```
Session::put('image',"/dist/img/".$user[0]->picture);
```

But then trying to retrieve it in the view by `picture` key

```
{{URL(Session::get('picture'))}}
```

So just fix one or the other